# Subscript out of range when trying to get last item of an Array

Tags: arrays, vbscript, hp-uft

For example, I have a string `A-456-BC-123;DEF-456;GHI-789`. And I need to search for second part:`DEF-456` with keyword `456`. The potential problem here is that the first part `A-456-BC-123` also has the keyword `456`. Currently my logic is that, `split` the string first using `;`, `split` each of it again using `-`, get the last item of this `Array`, search keyword `456`. Another thing is that I don't want to do a full keyword match like `DEF-456`, I only want to use `456` as keyword to locate `DEF-456`, in other words, `456` should be the last segment of the string I want.

Here are my codes:

```
FirstSplit= split("A-456-BC-123;DEF-456;GHI-789",";")

For each code in FirstSplit
    SecondSplit = split(FirstSplit,"-")
    'get Array Count
    Count = Ubound(SecondSplit)
    'get the last item in Array
    If SecondSplit(Count-1) = "456" Then
      'doing something
    End if
Next
```

Currently, an error will generate at `SecondSplit(Count-1)`, saying that `"Subscript out of range: '[number: -1]'"`

Could someone tell me how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The real problem is here:

```
SecondSplit = Split(FirstSplit, "-")
```

You should be splitting your element which you've stored in variable `code` from your `For Each` loop. By trying to split an array you should be getting a `Type Mismatch` error, but perhaps vbscript is forgiving enough to attempt and return a 0 element array back or something. Anyway:

```
SecondSplit = Split(Code, "-")
```

Also, to look at the last element just use:

```
If secondSplit(Ubound(SecondSplit)) = "456" Then
```

Subtracting 1 from the `ubound` would get you the second to last element.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to split it twice - what you're looking for is `Right()`:

```
FirstSplit = split("A-456-BC-123;DEF-456;GHI-789",";")

For each code in FirstSplit
    If Right(code, 3) = "456" Then
        ' do something
    End If
Next
```

Though this would also match an entry like `ABC-1456`.  If the `-` symbol is a required delimiter, you'd have to say `If Right(code, 4) = "-456"`.

Comment: Or use something like `InStr(1, StrReverse(code), "-")` instead of hard coding the number of characters to return from `Right()`.